# Cardinality of the powerset of the set $S = \{a,a,b\}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

We know that the Cardinality of the Powerset of a set S is given from: $|P(S)|= 2^{|S|}$.
Let $S$ be the set $S=\{a,a,b\}$, which has a cardinality of 2. Thus, the cardinality of the poweset of S equals 4 (2^2). When creating the actual powerset we have: $$P(S)=\{ \emptyset,\{a\}, \{b\} \}$$
We now need one more set inside it, to complete the 4 sets. Is this set $\{a,a,b\}$ or $\{a,b\}$  and why? Thanks!

Comment: $\{a,a,b\}=\{a,b\}$.

Comment: Yes, because the set $\{a,b\}$ (which is the same as $\{a,a,b\}$) is a subset of $S$. The powerset of $S$ contains **all** subsets of $S$.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, $\{a,b\}$ and $\{a,a,b\}$ is the same set. A set is fully determined by its elements. Writing the same element twice doesn't change anything, the elements of this set are still only $a$ and $b$.

Also, every set is trivially a subset of itself. So $\{a,b\}$ is indeed another element in the power set.

Answer (score 1):

When you are constructing sets, then for instance $\{ a, a, b \} = \{ a, b \}$. So you need to include $S$.

You can note this by the way we define the notion of a subset: A set $A$ is a subset of a set $S$ if each element $a \in A$ in $A$ is also in $S$, i.e. $a \in S$.