# Is the Final Clause of this Set Description Redundant?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, graph-theory

Consider: $E\subseteq\{\{x, y\} | x, y \in V \land x \neq y\}$

which describes a set of edges of a given vertex in the context of graph theory. This formula was taken from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_theory#Definitions) (I changed "and" to $\land$), and I want to know if the final clause $x \neq y$ is redundant. Sets are defined as being un-ordered and not containing duplicates as an assumption of the construct, so is it necessary to also state this *explicitly* in the constraints of the set?

Comment: That clause excludes [self-loops](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_(graph_theory)), which are excluded from simple graphs.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro This makes sense, would you be ok with providing it as an answer so I can accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to exclude one-element sets from $E,$ then the clause is needed.

For example, if $V=\{a,b\},$ then without $x \neq y$ the set $\{a,a\}=\{a\}$ would belong to $E,$ since $x=a$ and $y=a$ would satisfy the membership property for $E.$

The phrase "not containing duplicates" is a bit hand-wavey, and what is meant is that if duplicates are used in describing a set, then [the same set is described when the use of duplicates is eliminated](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3808324/13130).